# ¿Cómo hago que el overlay se posicione sobre la imagen?

Tags: html, css

Tengo dos fotos en una misma línea, pero quiero que cuando pase el cursor por arriba se despliegue un `overlay`. Tengo toda la programación lista, lo único que me falta es que el `overlay` con `position: absolute;` se posicione sobre la imagen en cuestión. Sin calcular los pixeles, porque en ese caso si se achica la pantalla me quedaría en distinta posición.

No me deja agregar imagen de ilustración, por lo que voy a describir lo que pasa. Al pasar el cursor por cualquiera de las imágenes, se despliega la capa correspondiente pero queda exactamente debajo de la imagen. El objetivo sería que quede encima. Adjunto mi código:

```css
/* section hs y ub */
.HsUbi figure {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.HsUbi figure img {
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 25px #00000080;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  height: 550px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.FHis {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.FUbi {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.HsUbi figure div div {
  width: 733px;
  height: 550px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.CapaHis {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #283618;
  opacity: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.6s;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.CapaUbi {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #283618;
  transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.6s;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.HsUbi figure .img1:hover > .CapaHis {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.HsUbi figure .img2:hover > .CapaUbi {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<section class="HsUbi">
  <figure>
    <div class="img1">
      <img src="./Img/IMG-20230214-WA0005.jpg" alt="Foto cuadernos" class="FHis">
      <div class="CapaHis">
        <h3>Nuestra historia</h3>
        <a href="./Pages/Nosotros.html">Conocé</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img2">
      <img src="./Img/20220206_082542.jpg" alt="Foto patagonia" class="FUbi">
      <div class="CapaUbi">
        <h3>Ubicanos</h3>
        <a href="./Pages/Ubicación.html">Ver más</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </figure>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:
para poder dar una posición absoluta al elemento hijo, al padre tienes que darle una posición relativa, luego poner el top en 0. reduci un poco tu código css.

```css
:root *{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.HsUbi{
  margin: 10px 20px;
}
.HsUbi figure {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.HsUbi figure .img1,.HsUbi figure .img2{
width: 550px;
height: 550px;
position: relative;
}
 .HsUbi figure img {
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 25px #00000080;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.HsUbi figure div div {
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.CapaHis, .CapaUbi {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #283618;
  opacity: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.6s;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.HsUbi figure .img1:hover > .CapaHis {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.HsUbi figure .img2:hover > .CapaUbi {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<section class="HsUbi">
        <figure>
          <div class="img1">
            <img src="./imgs/images.jpg"  alt="Foto cuadernos" class="FHis">
            <div class="CapaHis">
              <h3>Nuestra historia</h3>
              <a href="./Pages/Nosotros.html">Conocé</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="img2">
            <img src="./imgs/images.jpg" alt="Foto patagonia" class="FUbi">
            <div class="CapaUbi">
              <h3>Ubicanos</h3>
              <a href="./Pages/Ubicación.html">Ver más</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </figure>
      </section>
```